# How to edit Procfile in Heroku when using heroku war:deploy myapp.war

Tags: java, heroku, certificate, procfile

I'm trying to edit the Procfile in Heroku, however it seems like you can't edit it when using the command heroku war:deploy myapp.war to deploy the war file. Any suggestion on how i can either edit this, or run another shell script in web phase?

I've tried to include the Procfile directly with --include, however it gets overwritten by the default Procfile which is provded by Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heroku war:deploy` doesn't support a custom `Procfile`. However, you can customize the command using the following config vars:

- `JAVA_OPTS`
- `WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS`

You can set this with a command like `heroku config:set WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS="..."`